# Restarting an app in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to restart a program in Eclipse? (preferably 1-click)

I really wish the console view had something like a restart button that would kill the app and restart it with the latest changes.

This always takes me at least three clicks.  I click the down arrow next to the green circle with white triangle (play button) to open the dropdown menu, then I click to choose the Java main that I want to run, and then to stop I click the red square terminate button in the console view.  Is there any easier way to do this that requires fewer clicks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse 4.1
open:
windows->Preferences->keys

in the filter text type:   terminate and relaunch

In the binding add your binding (i use shift-F5)

For "when" select "In Windows"

This will do it in single shorcut for you.

Comment: Thanks.  It doesn't seem to work for me though.  I'm not quite sure what "In Windows" means.  Will it work with my cursor just in the text editor or do I need something special selected?  I'm using Ubuntu Natty Narwhal and Eclipse 3.5.2.

Comment: I have the same problem. For me it works only I run the program in debug mode.

Comment: This shortcut is present in the configuration lists yet does not appear working for me either.

Comment: It only works in debug mode. Can anybody make it work in the default mode?

Answer (score 3):

Or install relaunch plugin:

https://bitbucket.org/mantis78/relaunch-plugin/wiki/Home

which will enable you to restart anywhere

Answer (score 2):

If you use "build automatically", there is a good chance that your changes are applied on the running program, on the fly. As such, most changes will be effective directly without a need to restart.

If there is a structural difference and Eclipse can't inject the new code (for example if you change anonymous classes, or inheritance patterns), then you will be prompted with a dialog inviting you to restart the application in one click:

[image]

Exceptions are when you change the value of a static variable (or of the initialization of a class that won't be executed again until you restart the application). In this case indeed, you will need to restart explicitly with another method.

Comment: I'm not sure that's always true.  You're running in JBoss in your example, which I think is what gives you that ability.

Comment: @Ben - it works with any Java application, the screenshot was only an illustration. There are limitations, however, like I wrote. But as long as you have "build automatically" and you are debugging your program, it will try to replace code on the fly. More about it on [this very site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hot+code+replace).

Comment: Wow!  I can't believe I never realized this!  Thank you so much.
One important note is that you have to be in debug mode.  This won't work if you just hit run.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I changed a simple println statement to print a different string, but the running application kept printing the older one. I did save my file.

Comment: This method isn't useful for Spring Boot apps. When you just change an annotation, hot code replacement succeeds, but of course the application still needs to restart to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 1):

the console view has a terminate button (a red square) which stops the execution. then another click on the Run button (the green circle with triangle) begins execution again.
thats what i do - 2 clicks :)

Comment: It's only two clicks if you have open in the editor the file you want run - otherwise it's three.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse with Spring you could download the "**Spring Tools *X***" plugin.
This will automatically add a start and relaunch button to the top bar menu.

[image]

It should be available on *any* perspective.

Comment: Thank you! I used to have this button, until I had a bit of a cleanup of some rogue plugins in my Eclipse instance recently. I've been trying to find out how to get it back - mystery solved!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an elegant solution for this problem, but if your program is short running and you can live with a few instances here and there, you can just use the run command. Its default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>. Every time you press this, your application will restart. BUT! If you press this while your application is still running, another instance will be run because the "old" instance won't be automatically terminated.

There are ways to really terminate your application using shortcut keys, but that requires setting breakpoints and then using the "terminate" command, and that isn't very elegant.

Comment: *"...and you can live with a few instances here and there..."* -- Unfortunately this excludes all servers (such as web servers) that need to bind to a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

When developing my own network application, I have added a code to check if the older instance is running, and if so, then send an agreed command over network socket for graceful shutdown. While this approach may not be the best as universal solution, it allows clean shutdown of the previous instance, rather than just killing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way without plugin, every Eclipse !**

Click the project from of this icon at this time hold the shift Button, Project will restart (Terminate and relaunch) with **server port** also.

**[image: Like as:]**